# Using an installed SSH key from one stage into another stage

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feature/*
      - develop

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
 publicKey: $(public_key)

stages:
  - stage: PrepareEnvironment
    displayName: Prepare Environment
    jobs:
    - job: InstallSSHKeyJob
      displayName: Install SSH Key
      steps:
      - task: InstallSSHKey@0
        displayName: 'Install SSH Key'
        inputs:
          knownHostsEntry: <knownHost>
          sshPublicKey: '$(publicKey)'
          sshKeySecureFile: id_rsa
      
      - script: |
          npm install
          npm run build
```

I am trying to split this pipeline into multiple stages one for installing the ssh key and another for building. npm install needs an ssh key in order to connect and install from a repository in the given above pipeline.

This pipeline works fine and npm installs. but whenever i try breaking down the pipeline into different stages. meaning i try to break it down to a stage that installs ssh key and another stage responsible for npm install/build i get an error from npm install that the ssh key in not given. so is there a way in ado to pass the installed ssh key ?

Answer (score 0):

Each job (and thus by definition each stage) runs on a fresh hosted agent and none of the things that were done in the previous job/stage will be there. You would have to repeat the prepare steps for each job that needs these things to be present.

If needed you can use a template to ensure you don't have to repeat these steps in the YAML of each job. But they would be executed as part of any job anyway.

What you want cannot be done in azure pipelines using the hosted agents.

Comment: isnt there a work around or does that mean ill have to intall my ssh key each time i run a new job ?

Comment: Nope, there isn't. The hosted agents are ephemeral, they are destroyed after each job finishes and you get a completely clean new image for the next job.